# Is it possible to change IIS W3C timezone?

Tags: iis, logging

As I understand, the default timezone for IIS logging W3C, is UTC/GMT.
Is it possible to permanently change it? or I will have to convert it manually each time?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

As far as I remember, you can change the formats:

- W3C - records the logs in UTC
- IIS - records the logs in local time
- NCSA - records the logs in local time

Via:

https://forums.iis.net/t/1192949.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Change Log File Format to IIS, which records the logs in local time.

[image]

If you don't want to change Log File Format, another way is to query the log using Log Parser Lizard with the following script:

```
SELECT TOP 100 to_localtime(to_timestamp(date,time)) AS localtime, *
FROM 'C:\inetpub\logs\W3SVC\*.log'
```